# EF Core Cannot Save Related Data one to many

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

Im trying to save a new user into the users table with a new role. Here's the model and configuration.

When I insert the below entity, The role table gets populated with the new role, but the user entity is not being inserted.

```
    `var userEntity = new User
    {
        Id = 0,
        Active = true,
        Firstname = "Fname",
        Lastname = "Lname",
        Password = "test",
        Phonenumber = "2223334444",
        Test = false,
        Username = "test@test.com",
        RoleId = 0
        //                Role = roleEntity
    };
    var roleEntity = new Role
    {
        Id = 0,
        Name = "test role",
        Active = true,
        Users = new List<User>
        {
            userEntity
        }
    };

    context.Role.Add(roleEntity);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Middlename { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public string Phonenumber { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public bool Test { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }


    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}`
```

Here are the entity configurations.

`

```
 public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
 {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Role");

        builder.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        builder.Property(r => r.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(r => r.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(r => r.Active).IsRequired();
        builder.HasMany(r => r.Users)
            .WithOne(u => u.Role)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    }
}

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("User");

        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder.Property(u => u.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(u => u.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.Firstname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.Lastname).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.Phonenumber).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.Active).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.Test).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.RoleId).IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(u => u.Role)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}`
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you insert the user instead of the role? Does that make it persist both?

Comment: Why do you set the Id and the RoleId explicitly?

Comment: @J.N. If I do that, then it throws an error saying that "RoleId is required, as a foreign key constraint".

Comment: @Nikolaus : its just to specify that its a new record. doesn't matter if i set it or not unless its an existing entity.

Comment: Du you try to add both?

Comment: @Nikolaus: add both? you mean seperately? yeah then it works. I thought it was a problem with my configuration, but it isn't (just verified this whole model in a normal MVC App and it inserts the related data).

Comment: When you add the user, it throws an error, did you set the Role of the user?

Comment: @Nikolaus: Yes. Even if i add a new User with a role as a new property, it wouldn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake by using

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
```

instead of

```
context.Add(entity);
```

that's why the related entities weren't being added.

Comment: That makes sense. This only adds the current entry and not the graph.